# drop down default selection causing search to begin

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a search page with several textboxes that user can enter data in to search by.  There are date textboxes where a date range can be entered.  There is a drop down where you select which date field you want to filter on.

the date range textboxes are not enabled by default.  Only if you select a date field in the drop down can you enter a date.  The default drop down selection is ""  a blank.

if you select a date field and then change to another date field in the drop down everything is ok.  If you select a datefield in the drop down and then switch back to the default "" blank, it triggers the search.  I do not want this to happen.  I only want the search to happen when they click the search button.

```
  protected void ddlDateType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlDateType.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            txtSearchEndDate.Enabled = true;
            txtSearchStartDate.Enabled = true;
        }

        else
        {
            txtSearchEndDate.Text = "";
            txtSearchStartDate.Text = "";
            txtSearchEndDate.Enabled = false;
            txtSearchStartDate.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Can someone tell me how to stop the search from running when someone switches back to the default "" selection in the drop down?

---

I commented out the if else code and still get the same result.   Selecting anything but the the default no search is started, selecting default "" a search is triggered.

Comment: maybe add a: if(selected_index = "") return

Comment: Is your search method in your Page_Load event?

Comment: As the Drop Down List is performing a postback, it will be running the code in your Page_Load event.  Could you post the code in your Page_Load event, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be better off changing that logic to operate in javascript so that the entire page doesn't have to be posted back to enable or disable controls.

I have added some example code below that you would trigger from the client side event for selected index changed, which I believe is the onchange event. You can add this event in your code-behind as follows:

ddlDateType.Attributes.Add("onchange", "OnDateTypeChanged()");

This code also changes the class of the textboxes to include a TextDisabled CSS Class to visually indicate the textbox is disabled, but this is optional.

```
function OnDateTypeChanged() {
    var ddList = document.getElementById("ddlDateType");
    var fReadOnly = true;
    if (ddList.selectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        fReadOnly = (ddList.options[ddList.selectedIndex] != '');
    }

    var oTextBox;

    oTextBox = document.getElementById("txtSearchEndDate");
    SetTextboxReadOnly(oTextBox, fReadOnly);
    if (fReadOnly) {
       oTextBox.value = '';
    }

    oTextBox = document.getElementById("txtSearchStartDate");
    SetTextboxReadOnly(oTextBox, fReadOnly);
    if (fReadOnly) {
       oTextBox.value = '';
    }
}

function SetTextboxReadOnly(oTextBox, fReadOnly) {
    /// <summary>This method sets or clears the readonly flag on an textbox. It also updates the class information to
    /// ensure that the control is displayed correctly to the user</summary>

    if (oTextBox) {
        oTextBox.readOnly = fReadOnly;
        oTextBox.className = UpdateClassForReadOnlyChange(fReadOnly, oTextBox.className);
    }
}

function UpdateClassForReadOnlyChange(fReadOnly, sClassName) {
    /// <summary>This is an internal method used to update a class based on the readonly flag</summary>

    if (fReadOnly) {
        return 'TextDisabled ' + sClassName;
    } else {
        return sClassName.replace(/TextDisabled /gi, '');
    }
}
```